# Running accelerometer with interval

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want my accelerometer to run in a certain interval, so i used thread to do it. But now i am having a problem which is my app crash after sometimes, without clicking anything and just crash. For exmaple, if i set the interval as 5 second, the first 5 second works but at 10th second it will crash. Your help is much appreciated.

Main Page

```
package com.example.suntracking;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccelerometerMain extends Activity{

TextView showax,showay,showaxold,showayold,showaxdiff,showaydiff,showsx,showsy,showlatnew,showlongnew,showdate,showtime,showday;;
int timesec,timeminute,timehour,dateday,datemonth,dateyear,day,ampm;
String daytext,ampmtext,showazi,showele,shownoday,showra,showdecli,showh_angle,shows_time_hour,shows_time_minute,shows_time_sec,
sshowday,takeampmtext;
int timeval,taketimesec,taketimeminute,taketimehour,takedateday,takedatemonth,takedateyear;
int samintval;
float takeax,takeay,takeaxold,takeayold,takeaxdiff,takeaydiff,takesx,takesy,takelatnew,takelongnew;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Thread t;
volatile boolean shutdown = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accelerometer);
    initialize();
    loadSavedPreferences();
    t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (!shutdown) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(samintval);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Write your code here to update the UI.
                           Save_fetchPref();
                           run_accelerometer();
                           run_cal();
                        }

                        private void run_accelerometer() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent j=new Intent(AccelerometerMain.this,Accelerometer.class);
                            startActivity(j);
                            savePreferences();
                            loadSavedpreferences();
                        }

                        private void run_cal() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent j=new Intent(AccelerometerMain.this,Calculation.class);
                            startActivity(j);
                            savePreferences();
                            loadSavedpreferences();
                        }

                        private void Save_fetchPref() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    timesec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                                    timeminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                    timehour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    ampm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                                    if(ampm==0){
                                        ampmtext="AM";
                                    }else {
                                        ampmtext="PM";
                                    }
                                    dateday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                                    datemonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                    datemonth += 1;
                                    dateyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                                    switch(day){
                                    case 1:
                                        daytext="SUNDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        daytext="MONDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        daytext="TUESDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        daytext="WEDNESDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 5:
                                        daytext="THURSDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 6:
                                        daytext="FRIDAY";
                                        break;
                                    case 7:
                                        daytext="SATURDAY";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    savePreferences();
                                    loadSavedpreferences();
                        }

                        private void loadSavedpreferences() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
                            sshowday=savedata.getString("daytext",null);
                            showday.setText(sshowday);

                            takedateday=savedata.getInt("dateday",00);
                            takedatemonth=savedata.getInt("datemonth", 00);
                            takedateyear=savedata.getInt("dateyear", 00);
                            showdate.setText(takedateday + "/" + takedatemonth + "/" + takedateyear);

                            taketimesec=savedata.getInt("timesec", 00);
                            taketimeminute=savedata.getInt("timeminute", 00);
                            taketimehour=savedata.getInt("timehour", 00);
                            takeampmtext=savedata.getString("ampmtext", "AM");
                            showtime.setText(taketimehour + ":" + taketimeminute + ":" + taketimesec + takeampmtext);

                            takeax=savedata.getFloat("ax", 0);
                            takeay=savedata.getFloat("ay", 0);
                            takeaxold=savedata.getFloat("axtemp", 0);
                            takeayold=savedata.getFloat("aytemp", 0);
                            takeaxdiff=savedata.getFloat("axdiff", 0);
                            takeaydiff=savedata.getFloat("aydiff", 0);
                            takesx=savedata.getFloat("sx", 0);
                            takesy=savedata.getFloat("sy", 0);
                            takelatnew=savedata.getFloat("latval", 0);
                            takelongnew=savedata.getFloat("longval", 0);

                            showax.setText("x-acceleration :" + takeax);
                            showay.setText("y-acceleration :" + takeay);
                            showaxold.setText("previous x-acceleration : " + takeaxold);
                            showayold.setText("previous y-acceleration : " + takeayold);
                            showaxdiff.setText("x-acceleration difference : " + takeaxdiff);
                            showaydiff.setText("y-acceleration difference :" + takeaydiff);
                            showsx.setText("x-displacement :" + takesx);
                            showsy.setText("y-displacement :" + takesy);
                            showlatnew.setText("latitude :" + takelatnew);
                            showlongnew.setText("longitude :" + takelongnew);

                        }

                        private void savePreferences() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
                            Editor editor=savedata.edit();
                            editor.putInt("timesec",timesec);
                            editor.putInt("timeminute", timeminute);
                            editor.putInt("timehour", timehour);
                            editor.putInt("dateday", dateday);
                            editor.putInt("datemonth", datemonth);
                            editor.putInt("dateyear", dateyear);
                            editor.putInt("ampm", ampm);
                            editor.putString("daytext", daytext);
                            editor.putString("ampmtext", ampmtext);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
    samintval = savedata.getInt("samintval", 1000);
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showday=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshowdayaccele);
    showdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshowdateaccele);
    showtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshowtimeaccele);
    showax=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaxnew);
    showay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaynew);
    showaxold=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaxold);
    showayold=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvayold);
    showaxdiff=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaxdiff);
    showaydiff=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaydiff);
    showsx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvsx);
    showsy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvsy);
    showlatnew=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvlatnew);
    showlongnew=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvlongnew);
}


}
```

Accelerometer

```
package com.example.suntracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Accelerometer extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sm;
int samintval;
float ax,ay,axtemp ,aytemp ,sx,sy,axdiff,aydiff,latnew,latold,longnew,longold;
TextView showax,showay,showaxtemp,showaytemp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadsavedPref();
    initialize();
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer,sm .SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    savePreferences();
    finish();
}


@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}


private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}

private void loadsavedPref() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
    samintval = savedata.getInt("samintval", 1000);
    latold = savedata.getInt("latval", 0);
    longold = savedata.getInt("longval", 0);
}

private void cal_displace() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    axdiff= ax - axtemp;
    aydiff = ay - aytemp;
    sx = (float) (0.5 * ((axdiff)/(samintval/1000)) * (samintval / 1000)*(samintval / 1000));
    sy = (float) (0.5 * ((aydiff)/(samintval/1000)) * (samintval / 1000)*(samintval / 1000));
    latnew = latold + (sy / 111229);
    longnew = (float) (longold + (sx / 71695.8));
    axtemp = ax;
    aytemp = ay;


}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        return;
    ax = event.values[0];
    ay = event.values[1];
    cal_displace();
     }

private void savePreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
    Editor editor=savedata.edit();
    editor.putFloat("ax", ax);
    editor.putFloat("ay", ay);
    editor.putFloat("axtemp", axtemp);
    editor.putFloat("aytemp", aytemp);
    editor.putFloat("axdiff", axdiff);
    editor.putFloat("aydiff", aydiff);
    editor.putFloat("sx", sx);
    editor.putFloat("sy", sy);
    editor.putFloat("latval", latnew);
    editor.putFloat("longval", longnew);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

LogCat

```
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.632: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.642: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.652: D/libEGL(2298): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
02-07 04:52:44.652: D/libEGL(2298): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
02-07 04:52:44.652: D/libEGL(2298): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:     RVADDULA_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.1.2.04.03.00.125.097+PATCH[ES]_msm8974_JB_3.1.2_CL3905453_release_ENGG (CL3905453)
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): Build Date: 09/12/13 Thu
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): Local Branch: ss-h-project-sba-final
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.1
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298): Local Patches: 8963a7534e7db6c9821a277d9be96c4cf0af87fa Do not clear the color components unless mask set. This disable clearOnResolve when color mask is not set.
02-07 04:52:44.652: I/Adreno-EGL(2298):                  0558bffe422425e3a63d0802691301942f57995d Add the stencil
02-07 04:52:44.692: D/OpenGLRenderer(2298): Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 04:52:44.702: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.702: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.712: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:44.722: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298): java.lang.InterruptedException
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298):     at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298):     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298):     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:995)
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298):     at com.example.suntracking.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:60)
02-07 04:52:48.892: W/System.err(2298):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 04:52:48.982: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:48.982: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:49.022: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:49.022: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:53.992: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:53.992: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:53.992: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.002: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.002: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.002: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.012: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.012: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.012: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.022: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.022: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.092: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.092: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.092: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.102: D/TextLayoutCache(2298): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
02-07 04:52:54.242: D/AndroidRuntime(2298): Shutting down VM
02-07 04:52:54.242: W/dalvikvm(2298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41853898)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.suntracking/com.example.suntracking.Accelerometer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2294)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.example.suntracking.Accelerometer.loadsavedPref(Accelerometer.java:62)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.example.suntracking.Accelerometer.onCreate(Accelerometer.java:25)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-07 04:52:54.252: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     ... 11 more
```